# Where is the File Geodatabase Raster Dataset file stored?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, esri-geodatabase

I have a esri file geodatabase with a raster dataset. How can I find out which physical file the dataset is referring to?

(I am retrieving the file geodatabase through the internet. It all seems to go well, but the raster dataset is missing in the file database after retrieval. Zipping the file geodatabase before "transport" solves this problem. To debug the issue I want to see which physical files are missing/different between the zipped and not zipped databases.)

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a [mosaic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000n000000#GUID-6D22A44D-2830-4393-85D5-38FBF6CBB483) and didn't get the external files? "The raster datasets in a mosaic dataset can remain in their native format on disk or, if required, be loaded into the geodatabase."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I believe that it is not the case in my specific case. It has the standard raster icon, not the mosaic icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to talk about which file the Raster DataSet is stored in. ArcGIS uses a proprietary algorithm to save the Geodatabase structure across different files in the File geodatabase 'Folder'.

There is no one is to one correspondence between a Raster Dataset(or for that matter FeatureClass or Object Table) and a file within the folder.